# How do I get Samsung Pay on the Galazy S6 920f?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6

Based on what I've been reading, it seems like it should be preloaded, but my 920f doesn't seem to have it.  I also checked my disabled apps list and it isn't there.

Comment: Check updates, I updated yesterday and it was in the update. S6 t-mobile

Comment: Is it possible to download it directly from [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.android.spay)? Also, [is your device/carrier supported](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/app/samsung-pay#compatibility)?

Answer (score -3):

Update all your google apps from play store and also get this app : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.walletnfcrel

Get Going with android pay ! Remeber you won't be able to use Android Pay if you have a rooted phone.

Comment: I already have Android Pay. I'm asking about Samsung Pay.

Comment: Android Pay is not the same as Samsung Pay.